If $\int_Afd\mu\geq0$ for all $A\in\mathscr{A}$, then $\int f\chi_Ad\mu=0$ for $A=\{x\in X:f(x)<0\}$
I am self-studying measure theory using Measure Theory by Donald Cohn. I am confused by his proof of the following result:

Corollary 2.3.13$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f$ be a $[-\infty,+\infty]$-valued integrable function on $X$ such that $\int_Afd\mu\geq0$ holds for all $A$ in $\mathscr{A}$. Then $f\geq0$ holds $\mu$-almost everywhere.


Proof$\quad$ Let $A = \{x \in X:f(x) < 0\}$. Then $\int f\chi_Ad\mu = \int_Afd\mu = 0$ (since $f<0$ on $A$, yet we are assuming that $\int_Afd\mu\geq0$). $\dots$

I couldn't understand why $\int f\chi_Ad\mu = \int_Afd\mu = 0$. Basically, this is how I got stuck:
Let $A=\{x\in X:f(x)<0\}$. Then $A\in\mathscr{A}$ because $f$ is integrable which means it must be $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. We also have that $f\chi_A\leq0$. Then $\int f\chi_Ad\mu = \sup\left\{\int gd\mu:g\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ g\leq f\chi_A\right\}$, where $\mathscr{S}_+$ is the set of all nonnegative simple real-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$.
However, shouldn't such $g$ not exist?
Or, perhaps more appropriately, if $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x$ in $X$ then $A=\emptyset$ so that $\int f\chi_Ad\mu = \int0d\mu = 0$; if $f(x)<0$ for some $x$ in $X$ then there would be no $g$ in $\mathscr{S}_+$ such that $g\leq f\chi_A$, so that $\int f\chi_Ad\mu = \sup\left\{\int gd\mu:g\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ g\leq f\chi_A\right\} = \sup\{\emptyset\} = -\infty$.
$***************\ *$
So, it seems to me that the assumption $\int_Afd\mu\geq0$ for all $A\in\mathscr{A}$ implies that $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x$ in $X$. But why?
Here are some of my thoughts: I think we need to consider two cases:

Suppose $\int_Afd\mu=+\infty$, which means either $\int(f\chi_A)^+d\mu$ or $\int(f\chi_A)^-d\mu$ or both is not finite.

Suppose $\int_Afd\mu\geq0$ and it is finite.


However, I don't know how to proceed next.
I don't know if any of the above makes sense. I really appreciate it if someone could help me out here!
Update$\quad$ I just realized that everything below the "$***\ *$" doesn't really make sense, because the question want us to prove $f\geq0$ holds $\mu$-almost everywhere.

For a construction of the integral in this book, please see this post.

You are correct about the fact that the set
$$
    \{g \in \mathscr{S}_+, g \le f\chi_A\}
$$
is empty. But the definition
$$
    \int f d\mu = \sup\left\{\int g d\mu: g \in \mathscr{S}_+, g \le f \right\}
$$
only apply when $f$ is nonnegative. Otherwise,
$$
    \int f d\mu = \int f^+ d\mu - \int f^- d\mu
$$
given the integrals on the RHS exists. In this case, since $f \chi_A \le 0$, we compute
$$
    (f \chi_A)^+ = \max\{f\chi_A, 0\} = 0
$$
and
$$
    (f \chi_A)^- = -\min\{f\chi_A, 0\} = -f\chi_A
$$
So,
$$
    \int f \chi_A d\mu = \int 0 d\mu - \int (-f\chi_A)d\mu  = -\int (-f)\chi_A d\mu
$$
Now, since $(-f)\chi_A \ge 0, \int (-f)\chi_A d\mu \ge 0$ and thus
$$
    0 \le \int_A f d\mu = \int f \chi_A d\mu = -\int (-f)\chi_A d\mu \le 0
$$
or, $\displaystyle\int_A f d\mu = 0$

Thank you so much for your answer. I added an answer below based on my understanding of your answer with all details worked out. I just want to confirm with you, is my understading all correct there?

I really appreciate @ThànhNguyễn's answer. I would like to have all the details worked out and so I am posting an answer for my own record. If you find any mistakes, please comment below. Thanks a lot!

Proof$\quad$ We are given that $f$ is integrable. It follows that $\int f^+d\mu$ and $\int f^-d\mu$ are both finite. So
\begin{align*}
0 &\leq \int f^+d\mu = \sup\left\{\int gd\mu:g\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ g\leq f^+\right\} < +\infty,\ \text{and}\\
0 &\leq \int f^-d\mu = \sup\left\{\int gd\mu:g\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ g\leq f^-\right\} < +\infty.
\end{align*}
We next prove, via two steps, that $\mathbf{f\chi_A}$ is integrable ,where $\mathbf{A=\{x\in X:f(x)<0\}}$.
Step 1:$\quad$ We show that $-f\chi_A$ is a $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function on $X$. Since
\begin{align*}
(-f\chi_A)(x)=
\begin{cases}
0\quad               &\text{if $x\notin A$}\\
-f(x)\in(0,+\infty]  &\text{if $x\in A$}
\end{cases},
\end{align*}
it follows that $-f\chi_A$ is nonnegative extended-real valued.
Now, let $t$ be any real number. Since $f$ is integrable, it must be $\mathscr{A}$-measurable, then it follows that $\{x\in X:f(x)<t\}\in\mathscr{A}$. Clearly, $A\in\mathscr{A}$. Then $\{x\in A:f(x)<t\} = \{x\in X:f(x)<t\}\bigcap A\in\mathscr{A}$. If $t<0$, then $\{x\in A^c:0<t\} = \emptyset \in \mathscr{A}$. If $t\geq0$, then $\{x\in A^c:0<t\} = A^c \in\mathscr{A}$. Thus, for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align*}
\left\{x\in X:\left(f\chi_A\right)(x)<t\right\} = \{x\in A:f(x)<t\}\bigcup\{x\in A^c:0<t\} \in \mathscr{A}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $f\chi_A$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable.
Step 2:$\quad$ Consider $\int(-f\chi_A)d\mu$. Note that $(f\chi_A)^- = \min\{f\chi_A,0\} = -f\chi_A$. Since $-f\chi_A$ is a $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function on $X$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int(f\chi_A)^-d\mu = \int(-f\chi_A)d\mu = \sup\left\{\int gd\mu:g\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ g\leq-f\chi_A\right\}.
\end{align*}
For all $g$ such that $g\in\mathscr{S}_+$ and $g\leq-f\chi_A$, if $x\notin A$ then $g(x)=0\leq f^-(x)$, if $x\in A$ then $g(x)\leq-f(x)=f^-(x)$. Thus, $\left\{\int gd\mu:g\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ g\leq-f\chi_A\right\}\subseteq\left\{\int gd\mu:g\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ g\leq f^-\right\}$, and so
\begin{align*}
0 \leq \int(f\chi_A)^-d\mu = \int(-f\chi_A)d\mu &= \sup\left\{\int gd\mu:g\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ g\leq-f\chi_A\right\}\\
&\leq \sup\left\{\int gd\mu:g\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ g\leq f^-\right\}\\
&< +\infty
\end{align*}
Moreover, $(f\chi_A)^+ = \max\{f\chi_A,0\} = 0$, which implies that $\int(f\chi_A)^+d\mu = \int0d\mu=0<+\infty$. Hence, $f\chi_A$ is integrable.
Finally, we show that $\mathbf{\int_Afd\mu=0}$. The integrability of $f\chi_A$ implies that
\begin{align*}
\int_Afd\mu = \int f\chi_Ad\mu = \int(f\chi_A)^+d\mu - \int(f\chi_A)^-d\mu = -\int(-f\chi_A)d\mu.
\end{align*}
Since $\int(-f\chi_A)d\mu\geq0$ and since we assumed that $\int_Afd\mu\leq0$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
0 \leq \int_Afd\mu = -\int(-f\chi_A)d\mu \leq 0,
\end{align*}
which implies that
\begin{align*}
\int_Afd\mu=0.
\end{align*}

The proof of $f \chi_A$ is integrable is unnecessary, as $\vert f \chi_A \vert \le \vert f \vert$, and given $f$ is integrable, we can conclude immediately that $f \chi_A$ is integrable.

@ThànhNguyễn Oh, I see. You are right! Thank you very much!

@ThànhNguyễn So sorry, I think I am confusing myself again. Why would $|f\chi_A|\leq|f|$ and $f$ being integrable together imply that $f\chi_A$ is integrable? It seems to me that you were trying to say that $g$ being $\mathscr{A}$-measurable, $|g|\leq|f|$, and $f$ being integrable together imply that $g$ is integrable. But I couldn't see immediately why $\int g^+d\mu$ and $\int g^-d\mu$ are both finite.

Is it because $g^+\leq|g|\leq|f|\implies\int g^+d\mu\leq\int|f|d\mu=\int f^+d\mu+\int f^-d\mu$, which is finite? A similar argument can show $\int g^-d\mu$ is finite. Thus, $g$ is integrable.

Yes, you are correct.

@ThànhNguyễn Thank you so much!
